# Lost stack trace when exception is handelled with @ControllerAdvice annotated class

Tags: java, spring, rest, exception, exceptionhandler

I have a spring REST application. I throw all the exceptions from controller and handle them at a common place, a class named ExceptionHandlerControllerAdvice annotated with @ControllerAdvice. There I have multiple methods annotated with @ExceptionHandler to handle each type of exception. In these methods I send custom error json response. Before sending the this error json to the consumer, I exception's stack trace in logs. See Code-

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandlerControllerAdvice {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExceptionHandlerControllerAdvice.class);

    @ExceptionHandler(value = { Exception1.class })
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<ErrorMessage> Exception1Handler(HttpServletRequest request, Exception1 e) {
        logger.error("error message {}. Details:", e.getMessage(), e.fillInStackTrace());
        return new ResponseEntity<ErrorMessage>(new ErrorMessageBO(e.getErrorCode(), e.getMessage()), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(value = { Exception2.class })
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<ErrorMessage> Exception2Handler(HttpServletRequest request, Exception2 e) {
        logger.error("error message {}. Details:", e.getMessage(), e.fillInStackTrace());
        return new ResponseEntity<ErrorMessage>(new ErrorMessageBO(e.getErrorCode(), e.getMessage()), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

The problem is that I am losing actual stack trace which tells me exactly where the exception originated from. Anybody familiar with the problem? 
 
**[Edit]** See logs.

```
ERROR 2017-06-20 13:29:03,784 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] ExceptionHandlerControllerAdvice.runtimeExceptionHandler(28) | error message null. Details:
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.abc.products.hotel.advice.ExceptionHandlerControllerAdvice.runtimeExceptionHandler(ExceptionHandlerControllerAdvice.java:28) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) [spring-web-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) [spring-web-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114) [spring-webmvc-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveHandlerMethodException(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:379) [spring-webmvc-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.doResolveException(AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.java:59) [spring-webmvc-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:136) [spring-webmvc-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.resolveException(HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.java:74) [spring-webmvc-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1193) [spring-webmvc-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1030) [spring-webmvc-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980) [spring-webmvc-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) [spring-webmvc-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) [spring-webmvc-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat7-websocket.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.65]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
```

Comment: Which logger framework are you using? If this is slf4j, why aren't you just logging the exception object itself? (Note that you may be overwriting the stack trace explicitly.)

Comment: I'm using slf4j. I've updated my question with the logs. Can you please check once? I suspect Spring is overwriting the stack trace.

Comment: I tried logging the object itself and it worked. Thanks @chrylis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your log formatting, it looks like you're using slf4j. The API's `warn` and `error` methods are frequently used to log exceptions, and slf4j provides specific `warn(String message, Throwable t)` overrides that can use exception-specific formatting in logger implementations (e.g., print the message and the first N lines of the stack trace). Since these messages should almost never be suppressed, you don't lose anything from not parameterizing the message string. Just write `logger.warn("message", ex);`.

As to why you had the problem in the first place, you should have used `getStackTrace()` instead of `fillInStackTrace()`.